# URL Rewriting in htaccess specific demands

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have specific demand... I would like to make URL rewriting in .htaccess file that works on a next way:

If user open url:

```
/user.php?id=1
```

Needs to be redirected to:

```
/user/1/
```

If user open url:

```
/user.php?id=100
```

Needs to be redirected to:

```
/user/100/
```

If open:

```
/getJson.php?id=1
```

Needs to be redirected to:

```
  /user/1/json
```

If:

```
/getJson.php?id=99
```

Than:

```
/user/99/json
```

Also beside this I've additional question. I've create in my root folder next folders:

```
/user
/user/json
```

And I know if I create in folder /user one additional folder called /1 and have structure like this:
/user/1/

and if I in that folder create index.php so that we have situation like this:

```
/user/1/index.php
```

In that case my page will be accessible at /user/1/

But I know that is bad practice. Is it possible to avoid creating folders? I want to have just two folders:
/user and /user/json and that my page be accessible at next urls (for example):

```
/user/100
/user/50
/user/50/json
/user/100/json
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for big post..

Comment: So, what have you tried already?

Comment: Have you already read about the `mod_rewrite` module of apache?

Comment: Where are `user.php` and `getJson.php` files located?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module here

The rule for your requirement would be something like below. However I have not tested these rules

```
RewriteRule  /user.php?id=([0-9]+)  /user/$1 [L]
RewriteRule  /getJson.php?id=([0-9]+)  /user/$1/json [L]
```